# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "": error=2, No such a file or directory

Tags: java, python-3.x, apache-spark

I faced this issue when executing following script

./spark-submit /home/*****/public_html/****/****.py

I first used python3.7.2 and later python3.5.2 but still get the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "": error=2, No such a file or directory.
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such a file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)... 12 more`
```

Before it, I have several message output as

```
2019-02-07 11:30:18 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, localhost.localdomain resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx instead (on interface eth0)
2019-02-07 11:30:18 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2019-02-07 11:30:19 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I am able to exec python3 -V
I am able to launch spark-shell and pyspark

And I feel very strange that no message is shown between "".

For my python code, it starts with

```
import sys
import urllib3
import requests

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType

from CommonFunctions import *
from LanguageCodeParser import *
```

I also tried with a very simple python code

```
print("This is a test.")
```

Here are some message after execute `bash -x spark-submit test.py`

```
+ '[' -z /opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7 ']'
+ export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
+ PYTHONHASHSEED=0
+ exec /opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit test.py
```

However, it doesn't work. Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the contents of your .py?

Comment: `Cannot run program ""`.  it's not getting a path or filename.

Comment: Hi, I have added the beginning of my python code.

Comment: @Steve Smith: As it shows nothing inside "", how do I know which path or filename it does not get. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I found that setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` is useful

It will be good if this Environment Variable can be setup in

`/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-env.sh`

Comment: This saved my day. Thank you @Yu-Ting LIN

Comment: Can u explain better your answer ? I'm having the same error

Comment: in windows how to set this?

Comment: In addition to that setting, if you still have the same error also set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` and don't forget to set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=""` if you set that setting to lab/notebook before.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above, but in case of windows the spark-env.sh.template should be renamed to spark-env.cmd and the following should be inserted.

```
  set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Users\usr\anaconda3\python.exe
  set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=C:\Users\usr\anaconda3\python.exe
  set HADOOP_HOME=c:\winutils
```

please remove all comments starting with "#" in this file.
Hope the above works for you as well