# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError when converting RDD to pyspark dataframe with dbconnect

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, py4j, dbconnect

I am trying to create a new data frame and get an error.
I've managed to find the most basic form of code that returns the error:

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('a', 'b')]).toDF().show()
```

I have managed to run this specific code and of course this basic function on other machines so I believe it is a problem with dependencies or system settings on the new computer, but I couldn't find any solution.

I'm using python=3.8, pyspark=3.2.0, dbconnect=10.4.8, I cannot use other versions.

I can read existing parquet or csv files with no problem.

the error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 
3106.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3106.0 (TID 
319269) (10.102.13.109 executor 47): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "3": 
error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:275)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:209)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 26 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3029)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2976)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2970)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2970)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3238)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3179)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3167)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2651)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2634)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2672)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.$anonfun$executeRDD$3(SparkServiceImpl.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withCallSite(SparkContext.scala:2614)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.$anonfun$executeRDD$1(SparkServiceImpl.scala:147)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:330)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:424)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:444)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:33)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:94)
at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.withAttributionContext(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:31)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:205)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:204)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:225)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:419)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:339)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:330)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:302)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:57)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:137)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:73)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:60)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:98)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:431)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:410)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.recordOperation(SparkServiceImpl.scala:92)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceImpl$.executeRDD(SparkServiceImpl.scala:144)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.execute0(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:725)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.$anonfun$executeRPC0$1(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:477)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.executeRPC0(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:372)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler$$anon$2.call(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:323)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler$$anon$2.call(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.$anonfun$executeRPC$1(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:359)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.executeRPC(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:336)
at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCServlet.doPost(SparkServiceRPCServer.scala:167)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "3": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:275)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:209)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 26 more
```

does anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: the error states **Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "3": error=2, No such file or directory** -- I'm guessing somewhere it is mentioned `3` instead of `python3`?

Comment: see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570555/exception-in-thread-main-java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-error-2)